# Probability question: order matters vs order doesn't matter

Tags: probability

Consider the following problem:

Two numbers are picked at random from $1,2,...,n$, what is the probability that they are consecutive if they are picked with replacement (and without replacement)?

Now I solved it first considering that the order of the numbers matter, and then if the order doesn't matter:

**Order matters:** Let $\Omega$ be our sample space, then $\left | \Omega \right |=n^2$. If we pick with replacement the possible pairs of consecutive numbers are: $\left \{ (i,i+1) : i=1,...,n-1 \right \}$ and $\left \{ (i+1,i) : i=1,...,n-1 \right \}$ hence the probability of picking two consecutive numbers is: ${2(n-1) \over n^2}$.

Now if we pick them without replacement there are $2(n-1)$ possible pairs each with probability ${1 \over n-1}{1 \over n-2}$ hence the total probability is ${2 \over n-2}$.

**Order doesn't matter:** Now $\left | \Omega \right |={n^2 \over 2}$. By the same reasoning as before we have that the probability with replacement is ${n-1 \over {n^2 \over 2}}$ which coincides with what we got when we took the ordering into the account.

However if we pick without replacement and not taking the ordering into account there are $n-1$ pairs each with probability ${1 \over n-1}{1 \over n-2}$ hence the total probability is ${1 \over n-2}$

Now is this correct? It seems strange that the probability without replacement changes whether ordering is taken into the account while the probability with replacement remains constant. Have I missed something or is this just the way it is?

Comment: Write $I_n=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $\Delta_n = \{(i,i):i\in I_n\}$. The sample space with replacement is $$S_1= I_n\times I_n$$
while the sample space without replacement is
$$S_2 = S_1 \setminus \Delta_n$$
Note that $|S_1| = n^2$ and $|S_2| = n^2-n$.

Comment: If you're looking at your sample space without replacement, it will only have half as many distinct possibilities (2 ways to arrange each ordered pair), and so each pair will actually have a probability of $2\frac{1}{n-1}\frac{1}{n-2}$